# Excel vba to populate more than one sheet from a SQL database

Tags: excel, vba

I am not experienced in Excel VBA. I have an Excel workbook with more than 1 sheet. Each sheet should refresh on clicking a button within the sheet.

Providing here the code used with just 2 sheets as an example and have removed all sensitive data from the code. I have 2 issues/questions:

- What is wrong with the code? When I run it using a button click in
  each of the sheets I get a
  "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined."
- Also is the way I have added the connection correct? i.e. if I
  give this    document to someone else will they be able to Refresh it
  without    database name and password being asked? Since there is an
  EXEC    function used I am forced to use the Read-Write
  authentication which I cannot distribute to every user.

I am not sure how can I provide an Excel file as an example without revealing any sensitive data.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

    Range("G12").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database("""", """", [Query=""""])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$8")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A2:B3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("L17").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Query1").Name = "Qry1"

End Sub
Sub refreshTAT()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet

'connection string here
conn.Open ConnectionString:=";"
Dim sCust As String
Dim mthNum As Long
Dim yearNum As Long

sCust = Sheets("" & ActiveSheet.Name & "").Range("B1").Value
sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
mthNum = Sheets("Month & Year").Range("C2").Value
yearNum = Sheets("Month & Year").Range("C3").Value

Select Case sheetName
    Case "Sheet1"
        macroName = "Qry1"
    
    Case "Sheet2"
        macroName = "Qry2"
        
 
Case Else
    MsgBox ("Not a valid worksheet")
End Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries(macroName).Formula = "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database("""", """", [Query=""EXEC ExampleDataReport '" & sCust & "'," & mthNum & "," & yearNum & """])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries(macroName).Refresh

conn.Execute (Query)

conn.Close

End Sub
```

Regards